# cycle thru each parent category and show 3 entries from each category

Tags: categories, channel

I am looking to cycle thru all the parent categories of a category group, show three random entries (from the products channel) from each category, then go to the next category in the group.

I'd share some code, but I don't even know where to start.

My final code that works:

```
{exp:channel:categories 
    style="linear" 
    category_group="2" 
    parent_only="yes"
}
    <h1>{category_name}</h1> 

    {exp:channel:entries 
        channel="products" 
        category="{category_id}" 
        limit="3"
        orderby="title"
        sort="random"
        status="open|featured"
        cache="yes"
        refresh="5"
        disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination"
    }
        <p>{title}</p>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed this for a recipe website once and the code below seemed to do the trick:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="products" style="linear" show_empty="no"}      
  <h2>{category_name}</h2>
   {exp:channel:entries channel="products" dynamic="no" limit="3" orderby="random" category="{category_id}" }                  
     {title}
   {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

The channel param on the categories tag is required unless you only have a single channel. Multiple channels may also be specified.

see: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/categories.html#channel

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Alec's method works, but it might cause very high query counts due to the way EE generates nested Channel Entries tags. Take a look at the alternative method outlined in this post from EE Add-on superhero (and parse order master) Low. It achieves the same thing, but is *much* more performance friendly:

http://gotolow.com/blog/nesting-tags-and-performance-in-ee

And if you're like me and not excited about futzing with PHP, have no fear. This is actually a pretty simple and flexible technique to implement even if it might not appear so on the surface.

Comment: FYI, the same technique is possible without PHP, using Stash: https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Listing-entries-per-category